# nginx long get string and 502

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy for apache. we use large get parameters in our url strings.

I am noticing that certain long urls are returning a 502 bad gateway

example of a url that works:

```
http://example.com/car-sale/year/2004-2004/make/Buick/model/Rainier/engine/6+Cyl/features/Keyless+Entry:Front+Airbags+%28Dual%29:Trailer+Hitch:Daytime+Running+Lights:Alloy+Wheels:CD+%28Single+Disc%29:Adjustable+Steering+Wheel:Floor+Mats/drive/AWD/condition/Used
```

example of a url that doesnt work:

```
http://example.com/cars-sale/year/2004-2004/make/Buick/model/Rainier/engine/6+Cyl/features/Keyless+Entry:Front+Airbags+%28Dual%29:Trailer+Hitch:Daytime+Running+Lights:Alloy+Wheels:CD+%28Single+Disc%29:Adjustable+Steering+Wheel:Floor+Mats:Luggage+Rack/drive/AWD/condition/Used
```

Is this controlled by the large_client_header_buffers in nginx. I am kinda lost on the documentation. This is the current value for it in my config:

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 256k
```

If this is the right option. What value should i set it at?

Never mind this seems to be a memcached limitation, where the nginx is using a key longer than 250 for set $memcached_key

Thanks